# Retrieve the value using jquery (getJSON) and json

Tags: jquery, json

How to retrieve status field from json file using text field as source for identificator code?

My data.json file:

```
[{
        "code":"001",
        "status":"ready"
    },
    {
        "code":"002",
        "status":"not ready"
    }
]
```

My jquery file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#ticketsearch').click(function() {
  var ticketcode = $('[name=ticketcode]').val();
  $('.ticket').text(ticketcode);
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
  $('.status').text(data.status);
  });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you need to loop through until you find the `code` that matches, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ticketsearch').click(function() {
    var ticketcode = $('[name=ticketcode]').val();
    $('.ticket').text(ticketcode);
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
        if(obj.code == ticketcode)
          $('.status').text(obj.status);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

---

If it's an option, just simplify your JSON to where `code` is the key, like this:

```
{
   "001":"ready",
   "002":"not ready"
}
```

Then you can access it via that key, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ticketsearch').click(function() {
    var ticketcode = $('[name=ticketcode]').val();
    $('.ticket').text(ticketcode);
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
      $('.status').text(data[ticketcode]);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I like your second version, but $('.status').text(data[ticketcode]);
returns no value. PS. I updated my JSON file

Comment: @adpo - if you alert `ticketcode` what do you get? If it's not `"001"`, or `"002"`, etc...when it just isn't finding the key.

Comment: @adpo - Your file looks like I have above? No other syntax at all?

Comment: I just deleted the square brackets from JSON. And everything works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Which one do you want? You get back an array. If you want the first status: `data[0].status`. If the 2nd element: `data[1].status`

Comment: I will select the id from the text field and then submit. Can I use for example data[ticketcode].status

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of dictionary objects, so you'll need to use `data[0].status` up to `data[n].status`.

Comment: I will select the id from the text field and then submit. Can I use for example data[ticketcode].status

Comment: yup, if ticketCode is the id you want, then that's what you do.

Comment: Take a look at @Nick Craver's answer.  He has an example for you.